# Is there any way to tell PowerMock not to use MockClassLoader for all objects which are instantiated via java reflection?

Tags: java, junit, powermock, powermockito

I see *serviceClass* classloader type is *MockClassLoader*. Is there any way to prevent that? Is @PowerMockIgnore the only option?

class A runs with powermock and calls a method of class B via reflection

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class A {
@Test 
public void testA() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException{
    Class<?> serviceClass = Class.forName(B.class.getName());
    Object serviceStub = serviceClass.newInstance();
    Method method = serviceClass.getMethod("fun");
    method.invoke(serviceStub);
    }
}

class B{
public void fun(){
     System.out.println("fun!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load class, then you can specify class loader, for example:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class A {
   @Test 
   public void testA() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException{
       ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
       Class<?> serviceClass = Class.forName(B.class.getName(), true, classLoader);
       Object serviceStub = serviceClass.newInstance();
       Method method = serviceClass.getMethod("fun");
       method.invoke(serviceStub);
   }
}
```

But if you want that class will not be loaded by `MockClassloader` when it is loaded implicitly, then use `@PowerMockIgnore` it's the only way.

Comment: The issue is, I can't modify the existing codes and specify classLoader. I am concluding that, there is none other than @PowerMockIgnore which will ignore particular classes or packages which I tell to ignore